# Allow multiple mutex owners or specified number of concurrent code executions

Tags: c++, multithreading

There is a code I that I don't want to be executed by more than X threads (e.g. five) at a time. Every smaller number would be fine. I'm currently experimenting with condition variables, here is what I worked out so far:

```
void Manager::EnterQueue(Worker *w)
{
    {
        // Ensure stable work of std::queue
        const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueInsertMutex);
        workerQueue.push(w);
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unlock_object(queueMutex);
    while (workerQueue.front() != w)
    {
        // stop all threads not being at front of queue
        cv.wait(unlock_object);
    }
    workerQueue.pop();

    {
        // ensure that numOfAvailableObjects is checked by one thread at a time
        const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(counterMutex);
        if (numOfAvailableObjects > 1)
        {
            // limit is not exceeded. Fire up another thread
            numOfAvailableObjects--;
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(SOME_WORK_TIME_IN_MS));

    {
        const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(counterMutex);
        numOfAvailableObjects++;
    }

    cv.notify_all();
}
```

So the idea was:

- make `while` loop that passes only Workers that are first in queue
- if `numOfAvailableObjects > 1` then pass next worker by calling `cv.notify_all()` which (in theory) would resume all `cv.wait(unlock_object)`.

Of course it doesn't work as expected. `sleep_for` is executed currently by one thread at a time. Do you know any other alternatives that would work like `cv.wait()` that will stop threads until I tell them to resume?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a semaphore. Look it up.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. I've just Googled C++ semaphores and found this example ( https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/30142/semaphore-cplusplus-11 ) which looks very similarly to what I've shown in my question. Turns out that I've unconsciously implemented such semaphore. Despite of that, my code doesn't work as expected, could you look at it for a second? Maybe you will be able to spot a problem

Comment: Why don't you reimplement the logic using a well known, existing primitive instead of making strangers debug your code?